# Representation of groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, rotation

Can someone please explain to me the last sentence (in bold) from the following excerpt? It's from a set of [lecture notes](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/classf.pdf) on classical fields and GR (Ch.2 Groups and representations, p.16). I went through some formal definitions of group representations and the wiki article, but I'm still not sure how to understand this.

> If we are concerned with the effect of rotations on vectors, we associate each rotation with an orthogonal matrix such as
> $$M(\hat{k},\psi)  = \begin{pmatrix}
> \cos\psi & -\sin\psi & 0\\
>  \sin\psi & \cos\psi & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}$$
> When these matrices are multiplied, we get the matrix associated with the product of the two rotations:
> $$ R_3 = R_2R_1 \leftrightarrow \bf{M_3}=\bf{M_2}\bf{M_1}
>  $$
> **Matrices that are associated with all group members such that this relation holds, are said to form a *representation* of the group.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M(\hat k, \psi)$ is a rotation through angle $\phi$ about the axis $\hat k$. We can *represent* each rotation by a $3 \times 3$ matrix, in such a way that combining rotations one after the other gives a rotation that corresponds to the product of their respective matrices. The representation is a mapping of the group onto a set of matrices such that the group operation maps onto multiplication of matrices.

It is often useful to find a representation of a group as matrices because that allows us to use the methods of linear algebra on those matrices and then translate the results back into the language of the original group. Wikipedia gives an overview of group representations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation).

Answer (score 2):

Given a group $G$ (with elements $g_1, g_2, \ldots$ and group multiplication $\cdot$) and denoting the space of (complex) $n \times n$ matrices by $GL_n$, a mapping $M : G \to GL_n$ with the property $M(g_1 \cdot g_2) = M(g_1) M(g_2) \, \forall \, g_{1, 2} \in G$ is called a (linear) representation of the group $G$.

In your example, $G$ is the group of (proper) rotations in three dimensions with group elements  $g_1=R_1$, $g_2=R_2$, $\ldots$ $\in SO(3)$ and group multiplication $=$ matrix multiplication. It turns out that you can find (irreducible) representations for $n= 2 \ell +1$ with $\ell = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$. The case $\ell =0$ corresponds to the (one-dimensional) trivial representation $M : SO(3) \to 1$. The case $\ell =1$ corresponds to the three-dimensional (defining) representation of $SO(3)$, $M(R)=R$, and $\ell =2$ is a representation of $SO(3)$ by suitable $5 \times 5$ matrices. You should be familiar with all that from the discussion of angular momentum in your quantum mechanics course.